# Unable to parse with Alamofire and swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parsing, alamofire

I am trying to emulate this java code:

```
try {
        Connection.Response programacion1 = Jsoup.connect(URLProg1)
                .cookies(cookies)  
                .data(formData2)  
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)  
                .userAgent(USER_AGENT)  
                .execute();


        Document programacion= programacion1.parse();

        Elements table = programacion.select("table").tagName("datos"); //select the table.

        Elements rows = table.select("tr");


        FileWriter programacionTexto = null;
        PrintWriter pw1 = null;
```

with this Alamofire swift code by using AlamoFire 5:

```
AF.request(URLProg1, method: .post, parameters: parametersProgramcion, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseString
                                { (response3) in
                                    let value = response3.value
                                    let json = JSON(response3.value)
                                    let table = json["datos"]
                                    let rows = table["tr"]
                                    }
```

witch I do not know if it correct or not for the final objective. Nevertheless, that's my main problem when I run the app I can debug print (when desired) the HTML output but the response request brings nil (see picture), so json is also 0 and so on, and, hence, I cannot work with the data. Is like It does not parse or something like that. Can you please help me with this?

BTW I have trued to use responseJSON also but I see the same problem an the "no character around 0" issue also.

[image] This is the debug status

Comment: `value` is clearly a HTML string, not JSON.

Comment: @mag_zbc I think is due to the ResponseString operator. The issue is that Request value is nil, and I don’t know why, even though I can debug print it.

Comment: It's due to the fact that your API returns a HTML, not JSON. It's not like the server returns a JSON, and Alamofire magically turns it into a HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. What I have done now is to change the RensponseString to ResponseJSON and to use SwiftyJSON by using, both the Let value= response.value and by adding let JSONvalue=value as NSDICTIONARY (as said in the SwiftyJSON API) but the result is the same. In the result3.value I still have a nil. I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: What is happening is that you are getting a HTML as a response, not a JSON. What exactly is unclear? Are you expecting Alamofire to magically turn a HTML into a JSON?

Comment: No, from my understanding I need to parse it to obtain the JSON. What I did is to use the SwiftyJSON API following the mentioned steps but I could not get anything. An I don’t know if this is happening due to this “request = URLrequest? Nil” in the variables inspection showed while debugging”. shouldn’t I have other than nil value for this request response (even if HTML)?

Comment: Look at your `response.value`. It says `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//...`. This is not a JSON. Period. "Parsing" it will not magically turn a HTML string into a JSON. Using Alamofire's `responseJSON` will not magically turn a HTML into a JSON. `SwiftyJSON` will not magically turn a HTML into a JSON. Because you simply are not getting a JSON as a response. You're getting a HTML. I don't see what might be unclear about this.

Comment: What I did in Java is to obtain the connection and parse it to create a document which I can inspect element by element, creating tables and so on. I want to “translate this to swift” where I not as experienced and is taken me a lot of time to understand the APIs and some aspects

Comment: @mag_zbc ok I get it. Thanks! I will find out this then.

Answer (score 0):

Find it. Since the response is an HTML I used swiftSoup to parse and use it. Thanks everyone I did not notice that I was not getting a JSON object in response.